# Do xsel and xclip work only for copy and not for paste?

Tags: xclip, xsel

The usages of `xsel` and `xclip` seem to me all about the copy operation, whether it is primary or clipboard selection.

When I perform the paste operation, is it only by using mouse or trackpad, not via `xsel` and `xclip` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xclip` and `xsel` can both read (copy) and write (paste) the selection. Check the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip)  for the `-o` (not default) and `-i` (default) operations.

```
$ echo hello | xclip
$ xclip -o
hello
```